# Stop init.d from running, and go to terminal prompt

Tags: linux, console, startup

I'm running Rasbian (Debian?) on my Raspberry Pi, and have allot of auto-starting things in init.d. But what if I want to stop them all from running, and simply break into a terminal prompt? I've tried ctrl+c and I've tried esc, but none of the two seem to work.

Any suggestions?

PS: I can log in through SSH and modify whatever, this is not a question of being "locked out of my Linux". I'm just curious if there are any "hold down key X to go to failsafe prompt".

Comment: Is rebooting to start `/bin/sh` at boot instead of `/sbin/init` an option?

Comment: @lgeorget is right - you can almost definitely just pass the kernel parameter `init=bin/sh` from your bootloader - probably `grub`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to boot into single-user mode, like most flavors of Unix?

Answer (score 1):

All flavors of Unix has a way of starting in "single-user mode". This usually gives you a root prompt just as the kernel is handing over to the system initialization scripts.

One way of doing this on Raspbian Linux is to modify `/boot/cmdline.txt` so that it reads

```
init=/bin/sh
```

This will start a shell rather than handing over control to `/sbin/init` (which would set up networking and run other init scripts etc.)

You may also edit this file upon boot by

1. Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while starting up,
2. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit configuration,
3. Tab down to `cmdline.txt`,
4. Change the file as above and exit.

Related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3751/oops-i-need-runlevel-1